# Deploying a rails app to Elastic Beanstalk keeps failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I run eb deploy on the application, I get this error:

```
-hidden-@ruby:~/-hidden-$ eb deploy
WARNING: You have uncommitted changes.
Creating application version archive "app-9115-160205_135915".
Uploading -hidden-/app-9115-160205_135915.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
ERROR: [Instance: i-024e83b0ed9b09096] Command failed on instance. Return code: 5 Output: (TRUNCATED)...ies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/tiny_tds-0.6.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing tiny_tds (0.6.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install tiny_tds -v '0.6.2'` succeeds before bundling. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-024e83b0ed9b09096'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.                                

ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

I can install tiny_tds successfully on my local machine and on the EC2 instance, but I get this error when I deploy. I'm extremely new to ruby, rails, git and anything programming. Basically, I'm taking an application made for heroku and converting it into en EB environment.

Comment: Can you ssh to the instance and run `gem install tiny_tds -v '0.6.2'` so you can see why it is failing? I am not familiar with this gem ... does it have a native extension or some dependency that does not exist on the default configuration. You can also download logs and look for detailed error message. How to get logs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html

Comment: Fetching: tiny_tds-0.6.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing tiny_tds:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160208-24889-1votup9.rb extconf.rb
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... yes
checking for sybfront.h... no
-----
freetds is missing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Comment: So this failed when trying to install native extensions. You should ssh to the machine and try running gem install tiny_tds. You need since extra packages. You can find which ones by running gem install on the ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the version of tiny_tds in Gemfile
And try again.